# Why is my cursor position offset in FireFox on my main screen?

Tags: 20.04, firefox, websites

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now.  Maybe since my upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.

It was very difficult to capture, but here is a video that shows that when the LinkedIn.com page is scrolled then the cursor is offset.  It's very odd.

https://youtu.be/4e4psHTCxn0

You'll see the cursor is activating the controls when it actually isn't over the control but is below the area.  It's a very odd problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've discovered the problem.

Wrote a small script to print the cursor location while on that page.

```
function getMousePos(evt) {
  console.log("x : " + evt.clientX + "  y: " + evt.clientY); 
}
addEventListener("mousemove",getMousePos);
```

I just opened the console and then pasted that in and then began examining the x,y values.

Ha, but that wasn't the solution.  I scrolled up in the console and saw the following error message given by FireFox:

**FireFox Console**

[-- This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”. www.linkedin.com --]